# React-Native + Redux + ImmutableJS Memory Leak

Tags: ios, react-native, memory-leaks, redux, immutable.js

I have a strange memory leak in my React-Native app. It's a constant RAM increase.
My state is normalized, and then converted to an immutable state. There is a sockets handler which updates existing objects in state. This causes the RAM to slowly increase as new messages are updating state.

**State**:

```
const state = {
    entities: {
        2000: {
            1: {
                id: 1,
                name: "I am normalized",
                coordinates:[
                    {
                        lat: 0,
                        lng: 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            2: {
                id: 2,
                name: "me too",
                coordinates:[
                    {
                        lat: 0,
                        lng: 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        1337: {
            2: {
                id: 2,
                name: "me too",
                coordinates:[
                    {
                        lat: 0,
                        lng: 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            3: {
                id: 3,
                name: "also normalized",
                coordinates:[
                    {
                        lat: 0,
                        lng: 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    results: {
        2000: [1,2],
        1337: [2,3]
    },
};
```

This is then converted with `fromJS()` to immutable state.

I have a sockets handler, which passes the `action.payload` to a reducer.

```
action = {
    payload: {
        message_type: COORDINATES_UPDATE,
        messages: [
            {
                id: 1,
                coordinates: [
                    {
                        lat: 180,
                        lng: 180
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                coordinates: [
                    {
                        lat: 90,
                        lng: 90
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**reducer that handles the incoming action**:

```
case SOCKET_MESSAGE: {
    let newState = state;
    if(action.payload.message_type == "COORDINATES_UPDATE") {
        action.payload.messages.map((incoming_message) => {
            let id = incoming_message.id;
            let coordinates = incoming_message.coordinates;
            newState.get("results").map((data, entities_id) => {
                if(data.indexOf(id) > -1) {
                    newState = newState.setIn(["entities", entities_id, "" + id, "coordinates"], fromJS(coordinates));
                }
            })
        })
        return newState;
    }
}
```

This searches the `results` `Map()` for an existing `id`, if it does exist, it updates the entities object. As far as I know, there are no problems with this logic, the state properly updates and is reflected in the `render()` component, altho for debug purposes I am rendering an empty `<View />` as my whole app, and only updating state.

However each `setIn`, or `updateIn` increases RAM ever so slightly, and with the frequency of updates I get it grows to GB in minutes.

[image: Steady RAM increase]

Relevant Packages:

```
"react": "16.0.0",
"react-native": "0.50.3",
"immutable": "^3.8.2",
"normalizr": "^3.2.4",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
```

Comment: you have to check whether for each loop , whether the item and sub items are created with new Instance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Memory Stabilized]

I ended up trying out many different solutions from this thread and github, but the most time consuming(and sad) one worked out best. Taking out ImmutableJS.

Memory stabilized after I replaced it with lodash functions.

```
const newState = state; //just because i don't want to mutate state
let updates = {}; //put my updates here
return _.merge({}, newState, updates); //merge into an empty object
```

`reselect` expects a new object every time the state mutates, and i have a very nested state structure. hence i went with `_.merge({}, ...)` instead of `_.assign`

[image: Stable after 1000+ seconds]

There's still a very slight increase but this is way better than what it used to be.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, that's a huge one ;) 
You should probably check 2 things:

0) How many socket connections do you have ? You might have 5-10 and all the data is multiplied

1) Do you use redux-dev-tool? It might consume very big amount of memory in your case, consider to deactivate for production/testing

Comment: 0) 1 persistent connection; 

1) yeah, i tried turning that off. still memory usage but lower;

it seems to be intermediate maps that are created by immutable, I've optimized the update code a bit more, but over an hour it'll still rack up to a few GB of memory.

Comment: Are you sure that you only need to add keys to map "entities" which are keys of "result" map, is this logic correct?
You shouldn't create so many immutable structures but perform change as 1 big update, but still, I don't think you have memory leaks because of this code, if logic is correct I can help with update

Comment: entities is the dictionary, while result is the index; I'm updating a part of the dictionary. Socket updates are coming in batches with some of the dictionary updates, i have to find them in several dictionaries using the index.

Answer (score 1):

Normalizr is originally developed for browsers. The issue of memory consumption of entities is well-known, however, practically it has not been  regarded as a barrier because page lifecycles on browsers are short enough.

[Best practices to handle memory consumption of normalized data · Issue #47 · paularmstrong/normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/issues/47)

Meanwhile, in a native application, memory must be released properly. Unfortunately, there is no elegant library or solution at present. As compromise plans:

- A. Don't use Normalizr. Update every entity by yourself.
- B. Implement garbage collection on entities by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for this info, I will test this by taking out normalizr

Comment: I also have a strong interest in your findings as I am faced with the same issue at work. I am looking forward to your report.

Comment: I ended up taking out normalizr; instead remade the functionality of it(i need that structure), but unfortunately it didn't help.